# Allow web users to write files into folder

Tags: permissions, nginx, webserver

I have a web site running on Ubuntu server with Nginx installed and I made profile picture upload in Django. However when I try to upload a new profile picture it says

> [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/home/xyz/djangodir/media/profile_pics/profilepicxyz.png'

How can I allow users to write new files into the `/profile_pics` folder?

I am a beginner in Ubuntu and Nginx, so it might be a really easy solution.

My intuition is that it will be done using `chmod` or `chown` commands.

Comment: You need to redo whatever you did there: you -do- -not- set a webserver to a location  in /home/ Make nginx point to /var/www/ and create a dir in there that you open up for "others". "My intuition is that it will be done using chmod or chown commands." sure but not in a users /home/.

Comment: @Rinzwind Any exact reason why should I put my project in /www/? I followed digitalocean guide on how to deploy django project and they did put it in /home folder -

[guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#create-and-configure-a-new-django-project)

Comment: Security. /home$USER/ is intended for the owner of that home. Nothing else. Website by default go either to /var/www/ or to a dedicated partition. Oh and please read why they say: `~/myproject/` ... that is not `/home/$USER/` (a little bit less bad then what you did: their method has 1 big security issue: creating and then deleting a user called myproject can kill your website. Please keep /home for what it is intended for: to hold user and their personal data and settings)

Comment: @Rinzwind Okay, I'll switch to /www/ folder and after that will users have access to write their profile pics in the /profile_pics folder?

Comment: Yes. The -deepest- folder you open up for "others" with a chmod 666 (last 6 is important).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

Using /var/www/projectfiles as the webroot is a best practice.

Change the webroot owner using the below command

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/projectfiles
```

and the file and folder permissions are

```
cd /var/www/projectfiles
```

and run the following commands

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

then give 777 permission for /profile_pics

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/projectfiles/profile_pics
```

Comment: Could you explain me what these commands do? 
`find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`
`find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; `

Comment: find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; **find files and change permission with 644** 
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; **find directories and change permission with 755**

Note : You need to run these commands from /var/www/projectfiles/ folder